# Is it possible to refactor test in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have created some test case and ended up with bloated, and repetitive code on each method. Please have a look at the example below:

```php
public function test_customer_can_update_department()
{
    $admin = factory(User::class)->create();

    $customer = factory(Customer::class)->create(['registrar_id' => $admin->id]);
    $customer->assignRole('customer');

    $company = factory(Company::class)->create(['owner_id' => $customer->id]);
    $division = factory(Division::class)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);

    $department = factory(Department::class)->create(['division_id' => $division->id]);
    $newDepartment = factory(Department::class)->make(['division_id' => $division->id])->toArray();

    Sanctum::actingAs($customer);

    $response = $this->patchJson(route('departments.update', $department), $newDepartment);
    $response->assertOk();
}

public function test_customer_can_delete_department()
{
    $admin = factory(User::class)->create();

    $customer = factory(Customer::class)->create(['registrar_id' => $admin->id]);
    $customer->assignRole('customer');

    $company = factory(Company::class)->create(['owner_id' => $customer->id]);
    $division = factory(Division::class)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);

    $department = factory(Department::class)->create(['division_id' => $division->id]);

    Sanctum::actingAs($customer);

    $response = $this->deleteJson(route('departments.destroy', $department));
    $response->assertOk();
}
```

As you can see, there is some variable which has the same approach written over and over again. I wonder if I can reduce it into smaller pieces and make it more clean and readable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the repeated setup logic to a setUp function that's called before each test.

```
class YourTest extends TestCase {

 public $admin;
 public $customer;
 public $company;
 public $division;
 public $department;

 protected function setUp()
 {
        $this->admin = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->customer = factory(Customer::class)->create(['registrar_id' => $admin->id]);
        $this->customer->assignRole('customer');

        $this->company = factory(Company::class)->create(['owner_id' => $customer->id]);
        $this->division = factory(Division::class)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);

        $this->department = factory(Department::class)->create(['division_id' => $division->id]);
    }
}
```

You could also extract some functions to the base test class to simplify the workflow.

Comment: Okay, but how can I access those variables? just call it? or, using `$this->variable`?

Comment: @DonnyPratama adjusted my answer